# Automatic updating of calculation result in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm making my first steps in js and jquery and I'm trying to make simple calculation form, 
which

1. takes numeric variable form form in html (sum)
2. multiplies it by constat multiplier
3. multiplies result by a number choosen from dropdown list (total)

and does that on the fly, so to say updates result whenever any variable changes.
code below works, but total result does not update when sum updates. what am I missing here?

```
$('.pow').keyup(function () {

var sum = 0;
var multip = 4;
sum1 = sum;
$('.pow').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val())*parseInt(multip);
    sum1 = sum; 
});
$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));  });

$('.per').click(function () {
var total = 0;    
var period = $("#period").val();
$(".per").each(function() {
    total = parseInt(sum1)*parseInt(period);
}); $("#sum1").html(total.toFixed(2)); });
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle or code snippet?

Comment: sure: http://jsfiddle.net/wycg8a1g/3/

Comment: So now that I can see what the code does, what exactly is your problem, the only problem I see is the broken `<select>` that closes immediately .

Comment: for example - you choose size of 3 gb. then you choose period of 2. so far so good. now change size to 2gb, total remains 24 while i'd like to change to 16 according to changed size variable value.

Comment: don't get me wrong, thats not rude answer but what's wrong with dropdown? i'd just like to limit period variable to few options so another numeric value taken from form is not an option.

Comment: the easier solution would be to add `$('.okr').click();` after `$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));`. Assuming you already chose from the dropdown it will be fine

Comment: the problem with the dropdown is AS soon as I click it closes, i.e. I cant choose anything. To solve this issue I hold the mouse button down, so the dropdown wont close (this is not normal). Is this the desired functionality?
p.s. I did not get you wrong :P

Comment: oh i didn't noticed it, as i always hold, thanks.

Comment: currently the computing of 'total' is only triggered by click on the dropdown. solution would be, to create a updateTotal function and call it also with the key-up event. (but keep in mind, that there might be no initial value set...)

Answer (score 0):

working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fr7doc7/1/)

*You calculate totals on ( $('.per').click(.....);, so when you type a number above, nothing happens, because the code does not run)*

The easier way to do this would be to automate a click after typing a number.
Add this `$('.okr').click();` after this line here `$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));`

Like so:

```
$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));     
$('.per').click();
```

Assuming you already chose from the dropdown it will be fine, otherwise the dropdown wont have a value to calculate with.

Also, the problem with the dropdown is AS soon as I click it closes, i.e. I cant choose anything. To solve this issue I hold the mouse button down, so the dropdown wont close (this is not normal). **The reason** is because you do `dropdown.click() { dropdown.change() }` think about replacing this functinality